# Can Google Apps Script read txt line by line?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, google-apps-script, fetch

First, I want parse a html and fetch some line

with Google Apps Script, and it's showed

" The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "/link " "

and code here

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
var downloadContent = response.getContentText();
var doc = XmlService.parse(downloadContent);
```

I think because the html use html5, that GAS can't parsing,

---

so I try otherwise method to parsing string,
(read line by line and keep lines which I need)

```
var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
```

but GAS hasn't Scanner, and how can I do?

---

In fact, I want to go this url "https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/gossiping/index.html"

and fetch information in

```
<div class="r-ent">
...
</div>
```

Comment: You might find Spencer Easton's new library useful for parsing HTML: https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-htmlparser2-library

Comment: I will follow this git, thanks! @AndrewRoberts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Apps Script is JavaScript so you can use the split() method to split the text content into multiple lines by the newline character.

```
var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var lines = text.split(/\r?\n/);
Logger.log(lines);
```